# Add apps using custom master page

Tags: custom-masterpage

When I want to add apps using my custom master page only the Noteworthy ones are visible (Document Library,Custom List,Task).
If I switch, to another not custom master page (ex. seattle) all is fine.
Is there maybe a snippet I ought to add to show all apps?
Or maybe, is there another issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the following in your custom Master Page:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
   <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
   <!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

Source: 
http://blog.drisgill.com/2012/12/design-manager-bug-sharepoint-2013-rtm.html

Answer (score 1):

**This problem may occur due to the following reasons:**

- You may have used a system custom master page where some placeholders were deleted or its visibility set to false like "DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea"
- The app installation service timer job is disabled.

To troubleshoot the issue, you should revert the current master page to the default, non-customized version in order to load your Apps correctly. Alternatively, if you choose to retain your custom master page, ensure that any missing placeholders are added, as mentioned in **[Add an App Stuck on Loading in SharePoint 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/your-apps-stuck-loading-in-sharepoint-2013/)**